# Do calling internal methods on reverence to object break harmonisation

Tags: java, model-view-controller

I beginner and I try to use MVC model in app. There are three classes: MainFrame, DatabaseController, Database. Database contain array of DataSet objects.

My question is: can I use methods of DataSet object in Database Controller.
Somethink like this:

```
class Database(){
 ArrayList<DataSet> database;
...
public get(int index){
 return database.get(index);
}


class DatabaseController{
 Database database = new Database();

 public DatabaseController(){
 }

 public void addTransformedData(int index, Double[] data){
  database.get(i).setTransformedData(data);
 }

}


class MainFrame(){
 DatabaseController databaseController = new DatabaseController();

public MainFrame(){

 Double[] data = {...};

 databaseController.addTransformedData(data);

 }
}
```

Comment: In principle yes you could call any (public) method from anywhere, but in your example above you have to instantiate the object first. e.g. `public void addTransformedData(int index, Double[] data){ var database = new Database();
  database.get(i).setTransformedData(data);
 }` Obviously in that example it won't have any data in the list yet, but that's the general principle. If you don't know what I mean then read up on object-oriented code and some basic tutorials on C# in general.

Comment: Database object is  instantiate firstly in header. I have not written all methods of app for make an example more simple to understand. I have have only problem of that one line: `database.get(i).setTransformedData(data);`

Comment: sorry I missed that. Yes you did intialise it above. My apologies. So what's your problem with this line exactly? I don't think this code will compile, btw.

Comment: ArrayList is private and contain DataSet objects. So in that case I modify private variable of database by reverence to the object and calling an public method.  I consider if I shouldn't rather crate a public method in Database object for that purpose.

Comment: it's really a matter of opinion and taste I think, and how you intend the class to be used etc. What you're doing now does seem to slightly obfuscate what really happens when you run the "get" method, but then again you could just rename that method. Maybe clear documentation would help with that as well.